# Id of fragment in SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, sliding, pagerslidingtabstrip

My `SlidingTabLayout` contains three tabs that uses same layout and absolutely same code except of few lines... In order to use different SQLite database tables in each of them I keep them as separate classes. To make it more clear, my `public Fragment getItem()` method in `public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter` looks like that:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
    }
```

I don't like this approach and I would like to know how can I achieve the same result using one class(make each instance of the class use different table of database). I think it could be done by passing something like unique ID to each instance so it knows which table to use, but I don't have clear understanding how can I pass something like that in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the bundle might help you:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

switch (position){
    case 0:
        TabFragment tab1 = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("tableName", tableName1);
        tab1.setArguments(args);
        return tab1;
    case 1:
        TabFragment tab2 = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("tableName", tableName2);
        tab2.setArguments(args);
        return tab2;
    case 2:
        TabFragment tab3 = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("tableName", tableName3);
        tab3.setArguments(args);
        return tab3;
}
```